# Quote: getOrigOrderId vs. getReservedOrderId

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order, quote

Considering the class **`Magento\Quote\Model\Quote`**: What is the difference between the following two methods:
**`getOrigOrderId`**
**`getReservedOrderId`**
Thanks

......................................................
Is it right that a quote would have a corresponding order only after placeOrder would be called for the current quote?
Do the methods mentioned above help to fetch the corresponding order for a quote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::getReservedOrderId()` method is used when Order is placed and Quote is in the process of converting to a new Order. `reserved_order_id` then saved as new `increment_id` in sales_order table.

Also, PayPal Express module in Magento 2 uses reserved_order_id when before user is redirected to a PayPal page. It guarantees reservation of the order increment id once PayPal will redirect customer back to a website.

Neither `getOrigOrderId` nor `setOrigOrderId` used from `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` class.

Comment: @Pro-Magento thanks for the feedback. Happy to help